# Few level of console.log = false dump?

Tags: javascript, console.log

What's wrong with console.log ? :D
json_data is an JSON Object

```
var json_data = {'title':'X-test', categories:['abc','def','ghi']}
```

After it's declaration I am adding more properties:

```
 json_data.xAxis = {
        categories: ['abc','def','ghi'],
        labels: {
          enabled: 1   // <----  notice that property enabled becomes 1 
        }
      };
```

And then

```
console.log(json_data);
```

output:

```
categories: Array[7]
title: "X-test"
xAxis: Object
    categories: Array[7]
    labels: Object
        enabled: false       // <--- it's crucial!!  :)
```

So next let's make a more specific dump:

```
console.log(json_data.xAxis.labels);
```

`{enabled: 1}` <---- So the dump of only labels is correct

The first dump should have enabled:1, not false.

Why console.log() does that to me? :D

EDIT:

The variable json_data is set in $.each() few times - maybe it's because of that and lazynes of a console.log :)

Comment: `console.log(json_data)` returns me `enabled: 1` in both Firefox 35 and Chrome 40. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: @BenoitEsnard Chrome 40   but it's not the problem here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json_data));
```

Comment: It's not the answer for my question but thank You for making me see that enabled is somehow true in this whole json_data variable. :D